# Error in trigger "Variable does not exist"

Tags: apex, adderror

```
trigger preventDuplicateAcc on Account (Before insert , Before update) 
{
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new)
    {
        List<Account> a = [Select id,Name from Account where Name=:acc.Name];
        if(a.size() > 0)
        {
            a.Name.addError('Account duplicate not allowed');
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error on adderror line

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For questions like these, it's very helpful if you include the full text of the error message that you get (word for word, don't try to make any changes to the error). It might not make sense to you, but the more experienced eyes here will have a better chance of understanding what the issue is. That said, you may also want to look into [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5) instead of trying to write your own trigger to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is typed as a `List<Account>`, which has no `Name` property. You can only access `Name` on an individual `Account` sObject, which here is `acc`.

As an aside, this is a very inefficient way of managing duplicates. I'd encourage you instead to look at Salesforce's native Duplicate Management feature for this purpose.

As written, your trigger will immediately fail with a `LimitException` any time more than 100 Accounts are inserted or updated. If you insist on doing duplicate management in a trigger, you *must* bulkify your code. Complete the [Apex Bulk Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) unit on Trailhead to learn how.

Comment: Thank you David, It helped me .